# jsPdf - NestJS "ReferenceError: document is not defined" when using jsPDF's html method

Tags: nestjs, jspdf

I'm trying to use the jsPDF library to generate a PDF document from an HTML template in a Node.js environment. However, I'm encountering an error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Here is the relevent code:

```
generatePdf(formEntryId: string, customerId: string): ArrayBuffer {
    const template = this.templateService.getTemplate('testPdf')
    const doc = new jsPDF()
    doc.html(template, {
       callback: function (doc) {
       doc.save('testFile.pdf')
    }
  })
  return doc.output('arraybuffer')
}
```

I understand that this error typically occurs when trying to access the document object in a Node.js environment. However, I'm not directly accessing document in my code. How can I resolve this error and generate the PDF document successfully in a Node.js environment?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using `doc.html` will end up calling to [`html2canvas`](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which isn't viable in the `node` environment. [There are](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3507) a [few issues](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2805#issuecomment-684506292) around this [problem](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3392) and it looks like there's no real solution other than running a puppeteer instance (or similar headless environment) and generating the pdf through that

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I wanted to exclude running a puppeteer, but at the end I did.